# deriving Generic and ToJSON at the same time?

Tags: haskell, aeson, ghc-generics

I have a module `Foo.hs` which contains a definition which does not derive `Generic`:

```
-- Foo.hs
data Blather = Blather ...  -- Generic not derived here
```

And in another module I want to derive `ToJSON`:

```
-- Bar.hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

instance Generic Blather
instance ToJSON Blather
```

but it doesn't compile. If I derive Generic in `Foo.hs` at the definition site I can later derive `ToJSON` in another module.

Can I derive `ToJSON Blather` in `Bar.hs` without modifying the original `Foo.hs`?

Or is there a simple way to write `instance ToJSON Blather` by hand?

Comment: Does it work with the [`StandaloneDeriving` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html)?

Comment: Why don't you want to derive `Generic` where you define the type? Orphan instances are evil!

Comment: Yes, that would be the right solution, but at this point in time I don't want to submit a PR which modifies `Foo.hs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable `StandaloneDeriving` and use `deriving instance ...` since this doesn't require that the derivation is in the same module as the data type.

Example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, StandaloneDeriving, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Foo

deriving instance Generic Blather
deriving instance ToJSON Blather

main = undefined
```

Comment: Ah - I was following the recipe [here](https://artyom.me/aeson#records-and-json-generics) and just used `instance ...` not  `deriving instance`.

Comment: @ErikR Giving an empty instance declaration works for `ToJSON`, but not for `Generic`. The reasons are a bit subtle: `Generic` is a class for which deriving is built-in. `ToJSON` is a class for which generic "default signatures" and implementations are given.